Char * results in weird string output
I am pretty new (less than 1 year) in C-Programming and I am trying to print a chessboard position.
And for some reason, the following code return weird output every time.
I doubt that this is due to pointers and stuff, which are new to me.
in my int main() function:
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
     POSITION a = STARTPOS;
     printPos(a);
     return 0;
    }

POSITION is a  typedef struct;
in the printPos() function:
void printPos(POSITION pos)
{
    printf("%s\n", getBoardStr(pos));
    printf("%s\n", getBoardStr(pos));
    char * a = getBoardStr(pos);
    printf("%s\n", a);
}

in the getBoardStr() function:
char * getBoardStr(POSITION pos)
{
    BITBOARD i = SIZE_uINT64xCHAR_BIT_1;
    uint8_t iter = 0;
    char * out = malloc(65);
    
    while(i>0)
    {
         if(pos.WPs&i)      out[iter] = 'P';
         else if(pos.BPs&i) out[iter] = 'p';       
         else if(pos.WNs&i) out[iter] = 'N';
         else if(pos.BNs&i) out[iter] = 'n';         
         else if(pos.WBs&i) out[iter] = 'B';
         else if(pos.BBs&i) out[iter] = 'b';         
         else if(pos.WRs&i) out[iter] = 'R';
         else if(pos.BRs&i) out[iter] = 'r';         
         else if(pos.WQs&i) out[iter] = 'Q';
         else if(pos.BQs&i) out[iter] = 'q';
         else if(pos.WKs&i) out[iter] = 'K';
         else if(pos.BKs&i) out[iter] = 'k';
         
         else
            out[iter] = '.'; 

         i >>= 1;
         ++iter;
    }

    return out;

}


here BITBOARD is just a alias for uint64_t and SIZE_uINT64xCHAR_BIT_1 is sizeof(uint64_t)*(CHAR_BIT - 1)
NOTE- I am not new to programming, I am a python programmer with 5+ years of professional experience.
and here's the output

You Can Read Entire Code
https://smalldev.tools/share-bin/u6PjgqpQ
EDIT :
Thank you all, my code worked, I terminated the string with '\0' and freed the pointer from the memory, after its use...

We don't need or want the "entire code", so please try to create a [mre] to show us.

But as a guess, do you remember that strings in C are really called null-terminated string? Do you remember to add the null-terminator '\0' to your strings?

On a different note, what happens with the pointers that getBoardStr returns? Right not you pass them to printf, but what happens after that? Where do you free the memory you allocate? How can you free the memory if the pointer is just discarded after the output?

for one thing, your getBoardStr() returns a string without the terminating \0-character at the end... and it leaks memory too.

let me give it a try...thank you so much btw
